# Ring $C([0,1])$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

> Consider the interval $I=[0,1]$ and let $R$ be the ring of continuous function $I \to \mathbb{R}$ on the interval $I$. Let $M \subset R$ be the subset of functions which are zero at $1/2$, in other words:
>   $$M:=\{f \in R| f(1/2)=0\}$$
>   Is the short exact sequence of $R$-module
>   $$0 \to M \to R \to R/M \to 0$$
>   split?

I have showed that $M$ is maximal ideal in $R$ and $R/M \cong \mathbb{R}$. However, I dont't know how to show whether the sequence is split or not. I'm trying to claim that $\mathbb{R}$ is a projective $R$ module but have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

If you consider this sequence as an exact sequence of $\mathbb{R}$-modules (vector spaces), then it obviously splits (every sequence of vector spaces splits - it is a general fact) and one such splitting is explicitly given in the answer by *Tsemo Aristide*, who interpreted your question in this manner.

On the other hand if you ask if this sequence is a split exact sequence of $R$-modules for $R= C([0,1])$ (which seems to be your real intention), then **the answer is no**. Indeed, suppose that $s:R/M\rightarrow R$ is a splitting of the projection $p:R\rightarrow R/M$ in the category of $R$-modules. Pick $f = s(1)\in R$. Then $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$ and since $f$ is continuous, we derive that there exists $x_0\in [0,1]\setminus \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$. There exists a function $g\in R$ such that 
$$g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 1,\,g\left(x_0\right) = 2$$
For instance pick $g$ to be piecewise affine function that satisfy these constraints. Then $g\cdot f \neq f$ because 
$$(g\cdot f)(x_0) = g(x_0)\cdot f(x_0) = 2f(x_0) \neq f(x_0)$$
On the other hand $g \cdot f,f \in s\left(R/M\right)$, since $s$ is a morphism of $R$-modules, and also 
$$p(g\cdot f) = 1 = p(f)$$
Since $s$ is a splitting of $p$, we derive that $g\cdot f = f$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for so clear answer. Instead of continuous functions we consider $R$ the set of all function $I \to \mathbb{R}$? Again $M$ is also submodule of $R$ and $R/M \cong \mathbb{R}$. Now is the sequence split?

Comment: @Desunkid Yes, it splits. For each $a\in \mathbb{R}$ pick a function: $$f_a(x) = \begin{cases}a & \mbox{ if }x=\frac{1}{2} \\ 0&\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Then $s(a) = f_a$ gives rise to splitting.

Comment: Ah I see. Your $f_a$ in this case is not continuous and it doesn't work in $C([0,1])$. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see that it does not split as a sequence of $R$ modules:

If it were to split, then that would mean $M$ is a direct summand of $R$.

But given an element $f$ that isn't in $M$, you can always multiply by a continuous, piecewise-linear "V" function $g$ which is zero at $1/2$ to get a nonzero element of $M$.  This amounts to $M$ being an essential submodule of $R$.

Of course, a maximal right ideal $M$ cannot be both a summand and essential right submodule of $R$ at the same time.

Comment: @Desunkid No, I don't.  In your exact sequence, $M\to R$ is the inclusion map, and if this splits, that means $M$ is actually a summand of $R$.  It would mean $R\cong M\oplus R/M$, right.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's same idea with the answer @slup.

Comment: @Desunkid While all solutions may boil down to the same thing, I think what I've written is a completely different approach.  Part of my reason for writing this is that I thought it would be significantly simpler to explain.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient map $p:R\rightarrow R/M$ of the exact sequence $0\rightarrow R\rightarrow M/R\rightarrow 0$,  is the evaluation $p(f)=f({1\over 2})$, in this case $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow R$ defined by $g(a)=f_a$ where $f_a$ is the constant function defined by $f_a(x)=a$ is a splitting.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The idea is also very helpful.